# Using multiple scanners failed - Java

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I have a problem with Scanner class. I have a few methods which read certain input from the user, however after invoking first method others crash (cannot read input). I searched for the solution and it looked like adding "scanner.nextLine()" will solve the problem but it didn't.

```
public class GameController {

private int numberOfPlayers = 2;

private Board board = new Board('.');
String players[] = new String[numberOfPlayers];
char playersMarkers[] = new char[numberOfPlayers];

public void getPlayersNames() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Insert player " + (i + 1) + "'s name: ");
        players[i] = input.nextLine();
    }
    input.nextLine(); // <- this one was suppose to solve the problem
    input.close();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    GameController gc = new GameController();
    gc.getPlayersNames();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int array[] = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (scanner.hasNext()) {
        array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
    }

    scanner.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
```

Output:

```
Insert player 1's name: John
Insert player 2's name: George
1
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: What do you think `scanner.close` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting anything from `scanner` (in the `main` method) because you already closed `System.in` (when closing `input`, at the end of the `getPlayersNames` method).

You should not close `System.in` yourself, as it prevent any future attempt to read from this stream.

Comment: So if I understand well, I should close only ONE Scanner instance at the end of the application and do not close any other?